# ASP.NET debug fails to start google chrome - error crome.exe 0xc0000142

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2015

When I try to start debugging my ASP.NET application with google chrome. Chrome failed with the code 0xc0000142. Debugging with other browsers works. I have set Chrome as my default browser, and has not observed any other problems. Only Visual Studio seems to have problems with my chrome browser.

Any advise is appreciated.
Best regards,
Kaj Bromose

Comment: Hi. I have found the root cause. After disabling Kaspersky Internet Security (completely, and disable after restart), and a restart. Opening Chrome from Visual Studio works again.

Answer (score 2):

**1**. Make sure you close all running programs.

**2**. Right click on the Google Chrome icon at your desktop or Start Menu and select Properties.

**3**. Go to the Shortcut tab if you’re not already there, add the switch at the end of the target. By default the last character is double quote, so you’ll need to add a space then followed by --no-sandbox OR --in-process-plugins. Do take note that there is two dashes.

chrome no sandbox shortcut

[image: Chrome]

**4**. Now run Google Chrome as normal. You won’t see the 0xc0000142 or 0xc0000005 crash popup anymore.

References: https://www.raymond.cc/blog/fix-google-chromeexe-the-application-failed-to-initialize-properly-0xc0000142/

Comment: I am sorry to say - I did not work. I tried  --in-process-plugins It was unsuccessful. I did not try --no-sandbox since I dont want to leave my Chrome exposed to malware attack.

Comment: I have searched about the issue and found that even the latest update of chrome is unable to fix this issue. Either way you have to risk your chrome security for it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will stop using google chrome and shift to firefox :-(
Compromising security is not an option.

Comment: Hi. I have found the root cause. After disabling Kaspersky Internet Security (completely, and disable after restart), and a restart. Opening Chrome from Visual Studio works again.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the root cause.

After disabling Kaspersky Internet Security (completely, and disable after restart), and a restart. Opening Chrome from Visual Studio works again.